# Transforming/modelling a State-Space model as a Gaussian Process?

Tags: time-series, gaussian-process, state-space-models

Is there a way to model, or represent/transform, a State-Space model as a Gaussian Process?

Comment: The answer is yes if the (Contibous-Time) State Space is linear and if it involves Gaussian noise(s). One simply derive the covariance kernel. However the converse is not true beause some GP can have long memory. It is very interesting to represent a GP in State-Space form but I can not see the point at doing the opposite. Is this really what is wanted?

Comment: @Yves, and how would one derive the covariance kernel? Do you have any references?

Comment: You will find good material provided by Simo Särkkä  on [State-Space Representation of Gaussian Process](http://gpss.cc/gpss13/assets/Sheffield-GPSS2013-Sarkka.pdf) near slide #17. This (Finnish) source is closely related to that linked in the answer of @Chango. Since the state equation is a (Continuous time) autoregression, the covariance kernel of the vector state process can be given in a closed form involving exponential of matrices.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is for certain covariance functions the relationship is exact.

Code:
https://github.com/AaltoML/Newt/

Paper:
https://aaltodoc.aalto.fi/handle/123456789/19842